# Adding images to one line in layout with ratio

Tags: android

I am doing an android app that have images which are located besides each other,
every image has its own width, I want to add these images in one line to fit the screen width,
with the same ratio for every one
I wrote code to add this images but still to know how to set the width programmatically

```
    ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1);

    ImageView view1 = new ImageView(this);
    view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.a2);

    ImageView view2 = new ImageView(this);
    view2.setImageResource(R.drawable.a3);


    LinearLayout my_root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
    LinearLayout child = new LinearLayout(this);
    child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    child.addView(view);
    child.addView(view1);
    child.addView(view2);

    my_root.addView(child);
```

only image 1 and 2 appear but the third didn't appear because the width of screen finished
Any help !! 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must need to use weight parameter to do this.

Try below code:

```
   ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

        ImageView view1 = new ImageView(this);
        view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.a2);
 view1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

        ImageView view2 = new ImageView(this);
        view2.setImageResource(R.drawable.a3);
 view2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

Comment: Thank you its working, but not all images in the same ratio @pratik

Comment: for Example: my display width is 480, and the first image 315 and second 200 and the third is 190 these are more than 480. I need function to re-sit the images width according to screen width

Comment: but when you give weight=1 to each and every image then it will occupy same space to each and every image, on each and every device. So it is better to give weight=1 to each image.

Comment: accept and upvote the answer if you found it is useful, so others can take benefit of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Layout Parameters to set height and Width of views at runtime. 
like this

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    view .setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```